# The sections of a function

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I've been troubled with this analysis problem, it states:

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a function, prove that: 
>   $f$ is continuous $\Longleftrightarrow$ $f_x,f^y : \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$, defined by $f_x(y)=f(x,y) \quad$ ($x$ fixed), and $f^y(x)=f(x,y) \quad$ ($y$ fixed), are continuous in $\mathbb{R}$

My attempt:

$|\Rightarrow$) was too easy, just fixing the $x$'s and $y$'s and using some zeros. My trouble is with $\Leftarrow$. Assuming the continuity of $f_x$ and $f^y$ in all $\mathbb{R}$, in particular in an arbitrary $x_0,y_0\in \mathbb{R}$ we have that:

$\forall \epsilon >0 \quad \exists\delta>0$ such that if $|x-x_0|<\delta /2 \Rightarrow |f^y(x)-f^y(x_0)|< \epsilon /2$.
Also

$\forall \epsilon >0 \quad \exists\delta>0$ such that if $|y-y_0|<\delta /2 \Rightarrow |f_x(y)-f_x(y_0)|< \epsilon /2$.

I have to demonstrate that:
for an arbitrary point in $z_0\in \mathbb{R}^2$, with $z_0=(x_0,y_0)$. And $\forall \epsilon >0 \quad \exists\delta>0$ such that if $||z-z_o||_2<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x,y)-f(x_0,y_0)|< \epsilon $.

Triangle inequality tells me that $||z-z_o||_2=||(x,y)-(x_0,y_0)||_2=||(x-x_0,y-y_0)||_2=\sqrt{(x-x_0)^2 +(y-y_0)^2}\leq |x-x_0|+|y-y_0|$.

And $|x-x_0|+|y-y_0|< \delta /2 +\delta /2=\delta$, so $||z-z_o||_2<\delta$. But I'm stuck with the part that involves the sections of $f$, i.e. $f_x$ and $f^y$, and the function itself. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is false. Consider classic example of:

$$f(x, y) = \frac{xy}{x^2 + y^2}$$

and  $f(0, 0) = 0$. This functions is clearly discontinuous at $0$:

$$\lim_{t \to 0} f(t, t) = \frac{t^2}{2t^2} = \frac{1}{2}$$

However, all sections are continuous, as can be easily checked: sections other than $f_0$ and $f^0$ are continuous because $f$ is continuous outside of $0$, while $f_0$ and $f^0$ are continuous, because they're identically $0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, then my instructor was mistaken in the statement of the problem. So it's just correct that if f is continuous then it's sections are continuous.